# Insertar elemento en array php, en una posicion determinada

Tags: php, array

Tengo un array. Quiero insertar el "b" en la posicion 1, sin que se borre el elemento de la posicion 2 (deberia quedar en posicion 3 luego de insertar "b").

```
$lista=array("a","c","d");
```

resultado=

```
$lista=array("a","b","c","d");
```

1- como puedo insertar en una posicion determinada? hay una funcion de php para esto?
2- como puedo borrar un elemento de un array?

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con `array_splice()`, un ejemplo sencillo:

```
$original = array( 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e');
$insertar = 'b'; // 

array_splice( $original, 1, 0, $insertar );// el 1 es la posición donde se ubicará el nuevo valor
// $original ahora es a b c d e
```

Answer (score 0):

Sólo tienes que usar el método array_splice. En tu caso sería:

```
array_splice($lista, 1, 0, "b");
```

Te recomiendo echar un vistazo a la documentación de PHP. Saludos

Comment: gracias a todos,.